# Firebase Firestore not connecting

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem that drives me crazy. I try to populate Firestore db with some tests fields. First time when i tried it worked perfectly, i did some modifications and nothing seems to work right now. The problem is that set/add are never called whatever i do. I can create and log in without problems. I don't post layout because is self explanatory. A button that set data: add_ddb. Thanks.

```
class StartingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private val firebaseAuth by lazy { FirebaseAuth.getInstance() }
    private var uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting)
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.apply {
            setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp)
        }
        add_ddb.setOnClickListener {vieew->
            val detail = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
            detail.put("nameOfDocument","sdsad")
            detail.put("documentNumber","sdasdvc")
            firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document("asda").
                set(detail).addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"sdasdasdasda",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,it.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        nav_view.apply {
            setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                it.isChecked = true
                drawer_layout.closeDrawers()
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.nav_signOut -> {
                       signOut()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }

        recycler.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        }
        DisplayInRecycler(this).displayDetails(recycler)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(intentFor<ActivityAdd>())
        }
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return when (item?.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                drawer_layout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }




    fun signOut(){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        startActivity(intentFor<SignInActivity>().clearTop().clearTask())
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your rules allow you to read/write to the database

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Comment: It's very very strange, i don't understand why...

Comment: @IonuţGrigore Does this line: `Toast.makeText(this,it.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` display something? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Nothing...

Comment: @IonuţGrigore Have you tried to add a complete listener and see what is happening when the task is not successful?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes i did, same thing, is not executed, nothing seems to execute.

Comment: If you add this line of code: `Toast.makeText(this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` before this `val detail = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()`, do you get the message?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes. Everything is executed before add/set.

Comment: Please add your database structure.